# Angular 4 resolve component from dynamic HTML

Tags: angular

I am currently facing an issue while trying to parse and inject HTML into my application.

1. I get a string from an API
2. String is parsed, and some content is replaced by a tag at the service level. The new string looks like this:

   ```
   [mention]{\"label\": \"Stack\"}[/mention] with some other text
   and a second [mention]{\"label\": \"Overflow\"}[/mention] with text
   ```
3. Then the string is displayed by a component in the view

   ```html
   <div class="custom">{{ parsedString }}</div>
   ```

I tried multiple methods like using `innerHTML` with a sanitizeHTML pipe, and read some posts of people having this issue when adding router links to their HTML, but I seem to not understand properly how to use `viewContainerRef` in my case.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960) linked multiple times, but to me it's a mashed potato of code and I cannot get the logic behind it...

---

### Update

So I ended up using a `Pipe` to parse the string and have a template using each part of the string to display a component if needed.

1. My view component gets the string from an API
2. The view component inserts the string in its template and use a pipe to parse it.
3. The filter returns an array of strings which can be used in an `*ngFor` loop

**`view.component.ts`**

```html
<div *ngFor="let string of text | mentions">
    <ng-container *ngIf="string.label">
        <mention> <!-- We can use a component with dynamic HTML ! -->
            {{ string.label }}
        </mention>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="!string.label">
        {{ string }}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**`mentions.pipe.ts`**

```js
/* Angular */
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: 'mentions'
})

@Injectable()
export class MentionsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    tryParseJSON(string: string) {
        try {
            const json = JSON.parse(string);

            if (json && typeof json === 'object') {
                return json;
            }
        } catch (e) {}

        return string;
    };

    transform(value: string) {
        const regex = /\[mention\]([^[]*(?:\[(?!mention\]|\/mention\])[^[]*)*)\[\/mention\]/ig;

        return value
            .split(regex)
            .map((match: string) => {
                // The mention is a stringified JSON, so we want to parse it
                return this.tryParseJSON(match);
            });
    }
}
```

This may not be the best solution as it would mean using the pipe in an `*ngFor` loop each time **we know** that dynamic HTML will include mentions (in my case), but for now I am ok with this, until Angular provides a nice and secured way to detect and replace components in injected HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Angular blocks run time compile. So you need to do some tricks.
https://github.com/patrikx3/angular-compile => works on Angular 4. Not 5, so it has no future.

I've solved this problem using dynamic components.
I can recommend https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286 this guide.